# Foreach loop only updating first row

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, datatable, dataset

I am trying to create an insert statement for certain records in the database. 
So the `DataTable`could return 100 rows but in the `foreach` loop it is running the insert 100 times into the first row. I want the insert to run for each row in the `DataTable`.

```
string status = @"select j.*, " +
                 " (SELECT Status FROM jobstat WHERE jobstat.JobID = j.ID ORDER BY Sequence DESC LIMIT 0,1)  AS CurrentStatusCode " +
                 " from job_new j " +
                 " left join jobstat js on js.jobid=j.id " +
                 " where j.delivermemberid=j.jobownerid and j.jobdate= '2016-05-20' " +
                 " and j.isactive=1 and j.IsOnManifest = 1 " +
                 " Group by j.ID " +
                 " HAVING  CurrentStatusCode NOT IN ('DEL' )";

DataTable dtStatus = BaseDisplaySet.CustomFill(status, param);
DataSet dsStat = new DataSet();
dsStat.Tables.Add(dtStatus);

if (dsStat.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtStatus.Rows)
    {
        string InsertStatusSQL = @"INSERT INTO jobstat (JobID,CompanyID,Status,Descrip,Sequence,CompCode,StatusID,StatusDate,Comment1,Comment2, CreateMethod) 
                VALUES (" + int.Parse(dtStatus.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString()) + ", 171 , '" + dtStatusfield.Rows[0]["StatusCode"].ToString() + "' , '" + dtStatusfield.Rows[0]["Text"].ToString() + "' , '" + dtStatusfield.Rows[0]["ListOrder"].ToString() +
        "' ,0 , '" + int.Parse(dtStatusfield.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString()) + "' , '" + DateTime.Now + "' ,'WebService', '' , 'WebService')";

        BaseDisplaySet.CustomNonQuery(InsertStatusSQL, param);
    }
}
```

I also tried `foreach (DataRow dr in dsStat.Tables[0].Rows)` but that didn't work either. It still only updated the first row.

Comment: You are inserting `dtStatus.Rows[0]["ID"]` every time, rather than `dr["ID"]`. In fact, you never use `dr` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your variable `dr` instead of `dtStatus.Rows[0]` like :

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtStatus.Rows)
     {
         string InsertStatusSQL = @"INSERT INTO jobstat (JobID,CompanyID,Status,Descrip,Sequence,CompCode,StatusID,StatusDate,Comment1,Comment2, CreateMethod) 
         VALUES (" + int.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString()) + ", 171 , '" + dr ["StatusCode"].ToString() + "' , '" + dr["Text"].ToString() + "' , '" + dr ["ListOrder"].ToString() +
           "' ,0 , '" + int.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString()) + "' , '" + DateTime.Now + "' ,'WebService', '' , 'WebService')";

          BaseDisplaySet.CustomNonQuery(InsertStatusSQL, param);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use *dataRow* instead of *dtStatus.Rows[0]*. You simply not using foreach loop.

```
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtStatus.Rows)
            {
                string InsertStatusSQL = @"INSERT INTO jobstat (JobID,CompanyID,Status,Descrip,Sequence,CompCode,StatusID,StatusDate,Comment1,Comment2, CreateMethod) 
                 VALUES (" + int.Parse(dataRow["ID"].ToString()) + ", 171 , '" + dataRow["StatusCode"].ToString() + "' , '" + dataRow["Text"].ToString() + "' , '" + dataRow["ListOrder"].ToString() +
                "' ,0 , '" + int.Parse(dataRow["ID"].ToString()) + "' , '" + DateTime.Now + "' ,'WebService', '' , 'WebService')";

                BaseDisplaySet.CustomNonQuery(InsertStatusSQL, param);
            }
```